# WPF PRISM - Register view with region without resolving instance

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, prism

Is it possible to register a view by type with a region within the Module initialization without causing the view to be resolved (instantiated) until the view is request for activation.

A scenario for this is when we have view-first approach with a dependency on and external service. I do not want the service to be initialized until the user really requires that view and this will help improve performance because some external services cost time to initialize.

Note: Multiple views are register to the same region (eg. menu navigation style scenario).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this.  One has more documentation than the other.

1. Take over instantiation yourself by using View Injection, rather than allowing the Region to instantiate your view (called View Discovery).  This is pretty straightforward, but without knowing your solution, it'd be hard to know exactly what you are looking for.
2. Utilize the IActiveAware interface. In this scenario, you actually allow the view to be instantiated, but your view would wait for notification from the Region Manager that the view is active.  Here is a look at the IActiveAware interface (it's pretty self-explanatory): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.iactiveaware_members(v=pandp.38).aspx

And a small codesample:

```
public class MyView : IActiveAware
{
     private bool _isActive = false;
     public bool IsActive
     {
          get { return _isActive; }
          set 
          { 
               _isActive = value;
               if(value)
               {
                     //Good idea to thread this if you can
                     DoSomethingExpensive();
               }
          }

     }

}
```